# How to characterize a projective variety is Complete Intersection or Not?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $F = 2x_1^3+2x_2^3+3x_2^2x_3 +x_3^3$, $Q_1 = x_1^2, Q_2 = x_2^2 +x_2x_3, Q_3 = x_2^2+x_3^2$.

I want to show the following projective variety is NOT complete intersection:

> $M =\text{the closure of } \{[t^3: t^2x_1:t^2x_2:t^2x_3: tx^2_1:tx_2^2+tx_2x_3:tx_2^2+tx_3^2:F(x_1,x_2,x_3)]\in \mathbb{P}_7\}$

We know that there is no homogeneous ploy of degree 1 in $I(M)$, and find four degree two homogeneous ploy in $I(M)$. There are as following:

> $f_1 = w_0w_4-w_1^2$, $f_2 = w_0w_5- w_2^2-w_2w_3$, $f_3 = w_0w_6- w_2^2-w_3^2$, $f_4 = w_0w_7 - 2w_1w_4-2w_2w_5 -w_3w_6$, where $w_0,\dots, w_7$ are homogeneous coordinate of $\mathbb{P}_7$.

If I find a nontrivial ploy in $I(M)\backslash(f_1, f_2, f_3,f_4) \subset \mathbb{C}[w_0,\dots, w_7]$, all is done.

And after calculate we know $I(M)_2 = (f_1, f_2, f_3,f_4)_2$, where the subscript denote only consider degree two in this set.

And it seems that $I(M)_3 = (f_1, f_2, f_3,f_4)_3$, but the calculation is tedious.

Is there some easier way for this problem? Appreciated for all help and hints.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what $M$ is; are $x_1,x_2,x_3$, and $t$ coordinates on a copy of $\mathbb P^3$?

Comment: @TabesBridges Yes, they are on a copy of $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: You have a threefold $M\subset \mathbb P^7$ which lies in the intersection of four quadrics. The only way $M$ is a complete intersection is if it is equal to the intersection of the four quadrics, in which case its degree would be $2^4 = 16$ by Bezout. Now notice that $M$, being the immersion of a projective space via a bunch of cubic polynomials, is the projection of a Veronese $3$-uple embedding. There are ${4 + 3 \choose 3} = 7\cdot 6 \cdot 5/(3\cdot 2) = 35$ such polynomials, so the complete Veronese embedding $V \cong \mathbb P^3$ lands in $\mathbb P^{34}$ and has degree $3^3 = 27$...

Comment: ...Projecting $V$ from a disjoint copy of $\mathbb P^{26} \subset \mathbb P^{34}$ would yield a degree $27$ variety in $\mathbb P^7$, but that cannot be the case here. For each point of $\mathbb P^{26}\cap V$, the degree drops by $1$, but you also have to blow up $V$ at that point to resolve the indeterminacy of the map. So I think what you can do is check for points of $\mathbb P^3$ at which the map defining $M$ is undefined. This should, presumably, be at least $11$ (so that the degree of $M$ is $\le 27-11=16$), and $M$ is a complete intersection precisely if it is exactly $11$.

Comment: Note: I have been proceeding from your assumption that $I(M)$ is generated by quadrics. I think this all breaks down if that is not the case.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for your help.  As you say, we have a rational map $p : V \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^7$ by projection,  let $\phi : \mathbb{P}^3 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^7$ be the rational map defining $M$, is $p\circ v = \phi$, where $v$ is Veronese isom? And what is the $11$? And I should  check for what?  And can you write an answer below? Thanks .

Comment: Correct that $\phi = p \circ v$. The $11$ is the difference between $27$, the degree of the complete Veronese embedding; and $16$, the degree of a complete intersection of four quadrics. You should be checking for points in $\mathbb P^3$ at which the map to $\mathbb P^7$ is undefined. I don't want to write an answer until I know that the strategy works, but I don't have time to check the details myself.